# How to use double interfaces in multiple implementing classes in Java?

Tags: java, oop

So lets assume I am having the following stuff defined:

```
public interface IExportTool {
    void export(IReport iReport);
}
```

And then attempting to use it:

```
public class KibanaExporter implements IExportTool{

    public void export(IReport kibana) {
        kibana = (Kibana) kibana;
        ((Kibana) kibana).toJSON();
    }
}
```

But there are also other classes which would again be doing something like that too:

```
public class MetricExporter implements IExportTool{

public void export(IReport metric) {
    metric = (Metric) metric;
    ((Metric) metric).toJSON(); // might be something else here like toXML etc
}
```

}

Please note that both Kibana and Metric are implementing `IReport<KibanaRow>` and `IReport<MetricRow>` respectively, while the IReport interface looks like:

```
public interface IReport<T> {
    void addRow(T row);
}
```

I don't like all this casting, this doesn't feel right nor gives me autocomplete, so any suggestion how to do it properly?

Comment: Make `IExportTool` generic. Then change the class declaration to `KibanaExporter implements IExportTool<KibanaRow>` and similarly for `MetricExporter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've posted, it's clear that both `Kibana` and `Metric` are subtypes of `IReport`.

In that case, you can make the interface generic:

```
interface IExportTool<R extends IReport> {
    void export(R iReport);
}
```

And then change the implementations in this fashion:

```
public class KibanaExporter implements IExportTool<Kibana>{

    public void export(Kibana kibana) {
        kibana.toJSON();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class MetricExporter implements IExportTool<Metric> {
    public void export(Metric metric) {
        metric.toJSON();
    }
}
```

This version allows the compiler to understand and validate that only instances of subtypes of `IReport` will ever be passed to `export()`. Code using this will be validated by the compiler, such that `MetricExporter().export()` can only be called with an object of type `Metric` and `KibanaExporter().export()` with an object of type `Kibana`.

And with that, type casts are no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks! That works.. but I am having a hard time wrapping it around in my head understanding how that all works and why... what is `R extends IReport`? Any suggestion to read some tutorial on this stuff so I know how to do this on my own next time?

Comment: That's the Generics feature. You could check the generics tutirial from Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html), or look at this generics FAQ: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/Fundamentals.html#What%20are%20Java%20generics?